# RuntimeError: Working outside of request context Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying out a web application that captures video from the client, processes it at the server-side and prints appropriate message. I was able to capture the video in frames and process every frame. For displaying the frames back to the client, I used a code from the internet that yields the frame and renders it. However, there needs to be an if condition before yielding the frame.

```py
def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame, persons = camera.get_frame()
        if persons == 2:
            flash('2 people detected.')
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
              b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

The if-condition needs to be evaluated and display a flash message. But, whenever there are 2 persons in the frame, the server crashes with the error:

```
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nitin/Desktop/cheating detection system/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 462, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/Users/nitin/Desktop/cheating detection system/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/response.py", line 49, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
  File "/Users/nitin/Desktop/cheating detection system/system/routes.py", line 273, in gen
    flash('2 people detected.')
  File "/Users/nitin/Desktop/cheating detection system/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 389, in flash
    flashes = session.get("_flashes", [])
  File "/Users/nitin/Desktop/cheating detection system/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 422, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()
  File "/Users/nitin/Desktop/cheating detection system/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 544, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/nitin/Desktop/cheating detection system/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 33, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

I am new to flask and any help is appreciated.

Comment: How and where do you call `gen()`?

Comment: Try using with `app.app_context(): flash("message you want to flash")`